# Identificador no válido ORACLE

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle

Tengo el siguiente codigo `sql`:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT 
t300.g300cta AS NUMERO_CUENTA,
( SELECT SALDO FROM ( 
    SELECT gscf305.g305s01 AS SALDO 
    FROM gscf300
    INNER JOIN gscf305 ON gscf300.g300uuid = gscf305.g301uuid
    WHERE gscf300.g300cta  = t300.g300cta
    GROUP BY gscf305.g305fdia, gscf305.g305s01
    ORDER BY gscf305.g305fdia DESC )
WHERE ROWNUM <= 1 ) AS SALDO

FROM tabla t300

INNER JOIN gscf305 ON t300.g300uuid = gscf305.g301uuid
INNER JOIN cclf002 ON t300.G300CLI = cclf002.c001cli 
INNER JOIN gtgf006 ON gtgf006.g005tdoc = cclf002.c002tdoc 
INNER JOIN vcvf002 ON t300.g300uuid = vcvf002.v001uuid 
WHERE t300.g300tcta  = 'V'
AND (gtgf006.g005tdoc = 1 OR gtgf006.g005tdoc = 2 OR gtgf006.g005tdoc  = 6 OR gtgf006.g005tdoc = 8) 
AND TRUNC(vcvf002.v002fape) <= TO_DATE('2019/02/15','YYYY-MM-DD') AND (TRUNC(vcvf002.v002fcie) >= TO_DATE('2019/02/15','YYYY-MM-DD')-1 OR (vcvf002.v002fcie IS NULL)) 
AND gscf305.g305s01 >= 900000.00 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT g300cta FROM mrcj000 WHERE t300.g300cta = mrcj000.g300cta) 
GROUP BY t300.G300CTA, gscf305.g305s01
ORDER BY t300.G300CTA ASC;
```

Me lanza el siguiente error:

> ORA-00904: "t300"."G300CTA": identificador no válido
>
> 904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Por lo que entiendo no me está aceptando la tabla que está afuera del subquery `tabla300 t300` con la condicion dentro del subquery `gscf300.g300cta  = t300.g300cta`.

Estoy tratando de que me traiga un numero de cuenta y a su vez el ultimo saldo de dicha cuenta, la cuenta que me devuelva , la trato de comparar con la tabla que está dentro del subquery.

Comment: La tabla tabla300 tiene un campo llamado 'g300cta'?

Comment: No puedes usar la tabla `t300` en el subquery porque no la estas seleccionando.

Comment: @AntonioVenerosoContreras Si, la tabla tabla300 tiene un campo llamado 'g300cta'

Comment: @alanfcm como asi?, no entiendo

Comment: No puedes usar la tabla `t300` en el `WHERE` si esa tabla no es parte del `FROM`.

Comment: Podrías darnos más información sobre lo que estás tratando de hacer?

Comment: @Aritzbn estoy tratando de que me traiga un numero de cuenta y a su vez el ultimo saldo de dicha cuenta, la cuenta que me devuelva , la trato de comparar  con la tabla que está dentro del subquery

Comment: Tiene razón @alanfcm, en la subquery estás haciendo usando t300.g300cta para comparar, pero no la tienes en el 'from' (en el from de la subquery)

Comment: Este query parece demasiado complejo para lo que queres hacer. Podes mostrar de las tablas que necesitas los campos que necesitas, asi armamos una query mucho mas simple que devuelva lo que queres?

Comment: @gbianchi ya edite la pregunta con el codigo que lleva

Comment: uff.. yo no entiendo nada de ese query. Hay cosas que parecen que sobran por todos lados, o deberian estar en otro lugares, y no entiendo porque tenes que joinear 6 tablas para obtener valores de ninguna de esas 6...